# Numpy array manipulation

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like -

```
x =  array([0, 1, 2, 3,4,5])
```

And I want the output like this -

```
[]
[1]
[1 2]
[1 2 3]
[1 2 3 4]
[1 2 3 4 5]
```

I tried this code-

```
y = np.array([np.arange(1,i) for i in x+1])
```

But it makes a list with dtype object which I dont want. I want it ot be integer so that I can indexed it later.

Comment: You cannot have an ordinary numpy array with non-uniform shape.  That is, each row must be the same size if you want a 2d numpy array with the handy numpy indexing and slicing.  This is why you get a 1d array of 1d arrays, it's just like a list of lists, except each item is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And I want the output like this

Just outputting it that way is simply an of slicing:

```
import numpy as np
x =  np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

for i in range(1,len(x) + 1):
    print(x[1:i])
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, is

```
y =  [np.arange(1,i) for i in x+1]
```

suitable?  You can access the lists that make up the rows with `y[r]`, e.g.,

```
>>> y[2] 
array([1, 2])
```

or the whole lot with `y`:

```
>>> y
[array([], dtype=int64),
 array([1]),
 array([1, 2]),
 array([1, 2, 3]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])]
```

Also note that you can control the data type of the arrays returned by `arange` here by setting `dtype=int` (or similar).